# how can i fix the error: 'std::vector' has not been declared

Tags: c++

```
using std::vector;
vector<int> d1(n);
for (int i = 0, l = 0, r = -1; i < n; i++) {
    int k = (i > r) ? 1 : min(d1[l + r - i], r - i + 1);
    while (0 <= i - k && i + k < n && s[i - k] == s[i + k]) {
        k++;
    }
    d1[i] = k--;
    if (i + k > r) {
        l = i - k;
        r = i + k;
    }
}
```

I was learning Manacher's algorithm, and this was the code, but it gives an error:

> 'std::vector' has not been declared

Comment: kudos on using `using std::vector;` instead of `using namespace std;` :-)

Comment: When using something from the c++ standard library, you should always lookup the [reference documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) for the corresponding headers to include. They're always mentioned right under the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `#include <vector>` above `using std::vector;`